# HTML5 Audio tag not working with IIS7 localhost

Tags: html, audio, iis-7, localhost

The problem I'm working on solving goes much deeper actually, I'm setting the source to a data URI from an file input element.  When that wasn't working, I switched it out for a known mp3 on my localhost server where the dev website is hosted yet got the same problem.  The HTML5 Audio UI element loads but displays no audio to play.

To dig into the problem, I created a test page in the root directory of my localhost/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio_test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body>
```

The file is saved as `audio_test.html` and is accessed as `localhost/audio_test.html`.  If I access it this way, I get the exact same error as I get on the page I'm having the issue with.  If I access it through the browser as a file as `file:///C:/inetpub/mysite/audio_test.html", the audio element works.

I've spent close to two hours on this and am still dumbfounded.  Anyone know whats going on?

I checked my IIS7 MemeTypes and it has nearly every one in existence enabled.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? IE10/IIS8 works just fine with a copy and paste of your page.

Comment: Thanks Joachim,

I'm using Chrome/IIS7 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

After adding an audio file, it would play when I clicked my index.html file, but wouldn't work when I opened it using localhost.

This code is in my server file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

..it says where my content will be served from.

So I added all my content into my public folder (audio, images, css, index.html..), and it worked!

Comment: I don't think your answer is related to the question, `app` is exactly what kind of Object and where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

ADD MP3, Wav, and Ogg file in the htdocs folder of your localhost name on xampp and it will surely worked